# How to assign value to tableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have the following Swift code, which is mostly auto generated once a tableview is added:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    return cell.textLabel.text = "test"
}
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String?'
```

I have tried `!` (unwrapping) in the `cell.textLabel.text` syntax to no effect.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textLabel as a part of the UITableViewCell is optional and therefore you need to change your code to this:

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
return cell
```

To add on to this you should not be getting your cell using that method, you should use:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: It gives this error: '()?' is not convertable to UITableViewCell.

Comment: That is because you returning the text, you should return your cell after you set the text. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to be returning the cell, not text from cellForRowAtIndexPath. You also should be using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to get your cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = "test"
    return cell
}
```